# Find similar/duplicate field values in MySQL (Sphinx-related)

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

Let's say, I have a table `objects`. It has fields `id`, `name`, `misc`.

How can I find rows with similar or duplicate `name` values? I can see that MySQL can be used itself for searching duplicate values, but not for similar ones, eg. `PHP Hypertext Preprocessor` and `PHP Hypertext Postprocessor` (~90% of source value).

Can it be performed with Sphinx? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the details of Sphinx, but what you're talking about sounds like calculating [Levenshtein Distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Quickly googling for "sphinx php levenshtein" I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996791/sphinx-and-did-you-mean-suggestions-idea-will-it-work) thread which describes a method that might work for you. Hopefully that gives you something to go on.

Comment: Levenshtein distance is just a method to compute the difference between two given strings I'm aware of. What I need is the actual row set of rows with similar field values. This can be performed by dumb algorithms, but I want to find out if some smart solutions exist.

Well, thank you for noticing this.

Comment: No problem, sorry it wasn't what you were looking for. Good luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

The 'suggest' example from sphinx might be useful starting point.

http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2Fmisc%2Fsuggest