# 'best match' human name search/rank using Sphinx search

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm trying to add a predictive 'best match' name search functionality to a custom CRM I've built and I'm running into some issues. I decided to go with [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) thinking it would do what I wanted pretty much right out of the box, yet I'm having some issues. I understand the matching modes sphinx uses, but I'm not really sure how I'd go about getting something like this, for example:

If I query: `Mike Shinoda`

It should be able to pull matches like these, ranked by best match: `Mike Shinoda | Shinoda, Mike | Mike Shinoji | Michael Shinoda | Shinoda, Michael | Mike James Shinoda | Mike and Ike Shinoda | Shinoda, Miles`

What's the best way to go about doing something like that? I'm not married to Sphinx, I just couldn't find anything that looked like it would do the job better

I did already attempt implementing the suggestion in this stack question [Sphinx and "did you mean ... ?" suggestions idea. WIll it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996791/sphinx-and-did-you-mean-suggestions-idea-will-it-work), but it didn't really work too well because matching mode `SPH_MATCH_ANY` matched way too many records, and `SPH_MATCH_ALL` would pull in records like `'andrus Cheryl'` when the query was `'sheryl curry'` (because all the letters in `sheryl curry` are in `'andrus Cheryl'`

EDIT

I am only indexing one field: contact_name

Comment: can you tell what all fields you are indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly sphinx wont know that Mike = Michael. You will have to explicitly tell it such 'equivalences' - there is `wordforms` feature especially for that :)

> > because all the letters in sheryl curry are in 'andrus Cheryl'

Sphinx wont do that. Sphinx matches on whole words. It doesnt do 'rearanged letters' matches.

Unless you've specifically implemented that (maybe you have from the did you mean suggestions) - in which case its not really what you want.

Suggest going back to plain normal sphinx indexing (no trigrams) and then run a query like

```
"^Mike Shinoda$" | "Mike Shinoda" | "^Mike Shinoda" | "Mike Shinoda$" | (^Mike Shinoda) | (Mike Shinoda$) | (Mike Shinoda) | (Mike Shinoda)
```

using `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED` and `SPH_RANKING_WORDCOUNT`

with `wordforms` to take care of the Michael > Mike equivalence.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I was wondering though, it looks like the `wordforms` directive requires you to explicitly define relationships in a text file, for example `mike > michael`, but there are tens of thousands of names, I cant possibly know all of their expected wordforms.. I guess I was expecting it to match on the first `Mi` part, and then since `Shinoda` matched, it should bump `Michael Shinoda` higher than other matches where only the `Mi` in `Michael` matches.. I was playing with `min_infix_len` and `expand_keywords` and was slightly getting better results.. any more tips?

Comment: `expand_keywords` wont help you directly, in this case, because you want fuzzy matches, rather than just promoting whole words. You could enable `min_prefix_len` and set `enable_star=1`. Then add say ` | (Mi* Shinoda)` as a term to the above query, so include the prefix matches. But would still get "Michele Shinoda" which you might not want.